# Selecting text in Tmux copy mode

Tags: vim, tmux

I run Tmux in Vi mode. Vi-like navigation in copy mode works fine. However, I can't select any text. Neither v nor V switches to Vi-like text selecting mode.

What am I missing?

By the way, is it possible to display line numbers in copy mode?

P.S.: I'm running Tmux on Mac OS with Z shell

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**Short answer: <kbd>space</kbd> starts selection and <kbd>enter</kbd> copies.**

For future reference, I got this from the tmux man page:

```
       Function                vi             emacs
       Back to indentation     ^              M-m
       Clear selection         Escape         C-g
       Copy selection          Enter          M-w
       Cursor down             j              Down
       Cursor left             h              Left
       Cursor right            l              Right
       Cursor to bottom line   L
       Cursor to middle line   M              M-r
       Cursor to top line      H              M-R
       Cursor up               k              Up
       Delete entire line      d              C-u
       Delete to end of line   D              C-k
       End of line             $              C-e
       Goto line               :              g
       Half page down          C-d            M-Down
       Half page up            C-u            M-Up
       Next page               C-f            Page down
       Next word               w              M-f
       Paste buffer            p              C-y
       Previous page           C-b            Page up
       Previous word           b              M-b
       Quit mode               q              Escape
       Scroll down             C-Down or J    C-Down
       Scroll up               C-Up or K      C-Up
       Search again            n              n
       Search backward         ?              C-r
       Search forward          /              C-s
       Start of line           0              C-a
       Start selection         Space          C-Space
       Transpose chars                        C-t
```

Update: The `tmux list-keys` command will also list any custom key bindings you have.

Comment: Additional tip, you can check which tmux copy mode you are currently using with: `tmux show-options -gw | grep mode-keys`. If you want to change the mode permanently, add this line to `~/.tmux.conf`: `setw -g mode-keys vi` (or `emacs`). Then run `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf` to apply it.

Comment: for some reason `w` does not respect punctuation and `enter` does not copy on Mac

Comment: How do you paste the text afterwards, after tmux exits copy mode?

Answer (score 112):

You use space bar for the beginning of the selection and enter for the end.

copy:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
- <kbd>Space</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

paste:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: This should be the answer. It could be improved by explaining entering/leaving copy mode.

Comment: Great, brief answer.  Just a note to fellow vi[m] neophytes:  If you're using a modal editor or command line, you're going to want to make sure you're in insert mode **before** attempting to paste using the aformentioned `Ctrl+b+]`.  Obvious in retrospect, but sent me back and forth a few times until I cottoned on.

Comment: I think the formatting and conciseness would be an awesome replacement for the the "short answer" section in my answer. Is there a way to combine answers that gives credit where credit is due?

Comment: hmm... thinking further, I guess two answers are more appropriate, would just like to have this above the fold somehow.

Comment: is this expected to work with nano? When I press <kbd>space</kbd>, I just get the cursor on the bottom of the tmux panel.

Comment: The `ctrl + b` is leader key, which may vary on someone's laptop, for me which is `ctrl+a`. Just a note.

Comment: Works fine after :setw -g mode-keys vi (see: https://waylonwalker.com/tmux-copy-mode/)

Answer (score 38):

Upstream (2.4+) tmux changed how to bind for begin selection. To create a binding for what the OP is asking use `-T` and send-keys with `-X`:

```
# Use v to trigger selection    
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection

# Use y to yank current selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
```

Comment: My tmux copy-mode just stopped working completely and I couldn't work it out, this fixed it.

Comment: `tmux` upgrades break my configs more often than I'd like... :-(

Answer (score 30):

You can also set up your .tmux.conf file by adding :

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

which will enable 'v' and 'y' to enter visual mode and copy, like in vim.

([Source](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vi-mode-in-tmux/))

Comment: I'm getting "command not found: bind-key" in tmux 1.9a

Comment: Oops, I put it in my .zshrc by accident, nvm :)

Comment: This stuff's changed in newer Tmux versions. It's now `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi ...`

Comment: see above https://superuser.com/a/1204738/48390 for up-to-date solution with newer Tmux versions

Answer (score 5):

I find entering vi mode easily to be my bottleneck for which I use the following:

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi  
unbind [
bind-key -n F2 copy-mode
```