# Vim yank to tmux clipboard

Tags: vim, tmux

I see a lot of explanations of how to make vim copy to the system clipboard (involving xclip for linux or pbcopy or OSX), but I would like to yank to the tmux clipboard. To be clear, what I want is to position my cursor over a word and hit something like `"*yiw` and then hop over to another window with tmux (maybe one where I want to paste a large URL for curl or wget) and press `Ctrl-B ]` to paste (or with whatever tmux prefix key you use). Thanks for help that any one can offer. It would be awesome if this is possible.

Comment: Why don't you simply install a vim built with clipboard support?

Comment: That is what I have decided on. It still isn't really satisfactory for a headless machine (without X installed), but it works fine for my usual setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear why you should use tmux clipboard.

I find it easier to copy to system clipboard from vim or any other application and them paste it on tmux. You could try following on your ~/.tmux.conf:

```
bind-key -n C-v run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel clipboard)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
```

This allows to paste from system clipboard to tmux using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>.

For further information on this approach: [Tmux: Clipboard Integration](http://grota.github.io/blog/2012/05/08/tmux-clipboard-integration/).

Comment: You are correct. Using a system clipboard as an intermediary seems to be the way to go. Do you know if vim can be configured to yank to a clipboard other that xclip? My idea is that if it could, then this could work on a headless machine without X installed. The binding you gave (and the ones in the link) could certainly be adapted to use another clipboard program.

Comment: I believe vim uses the system clipboard, unaware if it is xclip or not. You may find additional information in `:help 'clipboard'` and [on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11489440/717124).

Comment: This does not answer the question. I explicitly want to isolate the system clipboard, vim clipboard and tmux clipboard because I actually want to hold multiple different buffers in different contexts. This solution will require corrupting my system clipboard every time I want to copy something on tmux.

Comment: There are (at least) 2 good reasons for needing the tmux buffer instead of the system one: when being logged over SSH without the `-X` option (i.e without X11 forwarding), or when the Vim version on the server is compiled without clipboard access (and you do not have the rights to change it).

Answer (score 16):

If youre working on a terminal and not a local vim process consider using [vim-tbone](https://github.com/tpope/vim-tbone) which enables storing selections to the tmux buffer. It is a basic configuration to map the :Tyank :Tput commands to keyboard shortcuts of your choice (I use ty and tp respectively)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it actually answers the original question. The currently accepted answer dodges the question.

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Comment: I forgot I had this vim plugin installed. It does _exactly_ what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to keep the tmux clipboard and system clipboard separate. A little more explanation [here](https://n8henrie.com/2021/05/copy-and-paste-between-vim-selection-and-tmux/), but these are the mappings I use:

```
vnoremap <leader>tc y<cr>:call system("tmux load-buffer -", @0)<cr>gv
nnoremap <leader>tp :let @0 = system("tmux save-buffer -")<cr>"0p<cr>g;
```

The main advantage compared to other strategies I've seen is that this faithfully copies the vim selection (including block selection) instead of working line-wise. Similarly, it pastes the tmux buffer at the cursor instead of working line-wise.

One disadvantage would be that for copying it requires a visual selection (instead of e.g. just a movement).

EDIT: If desired, it would probably be easy to modify the copy mapping to something like `nnoremap <leader>tc :call system("tmux load-buffer -", @0)` -- this would require the user to first yank the text of interest, then would copy whatever they had yanked to Tmux. The advantage here would be that normal vim movement-yank would work without first requiring a visual selection.

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

In Vim, `:only | set nonu`
In Tmux, `ctrl-b z`

This makes the buffer occupy entire terminal screen. Then you can use tmux to select the text.

Another way is using tmux block selection:

1. `ctrl-b [` to enter selection mode
2. `ctrl-v SPACE` to enter [block selection](https://superuser.com/questions/395158/tmux-copy-mode-select-text-block) mode
3. select ONLY the text you want to copy.

Comment: You would probably also need to do `set nolist` in case your Vim config displays special characters (whitespaces, newlines).